# Capistrano can't find .jar file

Tags: java, ruby, capistrano

I'm writing a code which will minify and gzip certain CSS and JS files in my web site and then deploy them to online server. In my deploy.rb file I have:

```
namespace :deploy do

task :start do

end

task :stop do

end

task :finalize_update do

    run "LANG=C find #{release_path} -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/d1b03c1ee47aaa75040d7c45c4b77a2b/87c8273ed98d70c2e5c56cc487598a0e/g' {} \\;"

    end

task :minify do
#declare compressor
compressor = "java -jar /home/yui_compressor/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"
#name of the javascript files to be minify and compressed
js_list = ["filter","onBoarding"]
javascript_path = #{current_path}/js
run  "cd #{javascript_path}"
js_list.each do |js|
run "#{compressor} --type js #{js}.js -o #{js}.min.js"
run "gzip -c #{js}.min.js >#{js}.min.js.gz"
end

#name of the style files to be minify and compressed
css_list = ["styles"]
css_path = #{current_path}/css
run ("cd #{css_path}")
css_list.each do |css|
run "#{compressor} --type css #{css}.css -o #{css}.min.css"
run "gzip -c #{css}.min.css >#{js}.min.css.gz"
end

end

task :restart do

end
before "deploy:", "minify"

after "deploy:restart" do

    #run "find #{release_path} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \\;"

    #run "find #{release_path} -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \\;"

end

end
```

As you can see I'm using YUI Compressor. The problem is:

```
failed: "sh -c 'java -jar /home/yui_compressor/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type js filter.js -o filter.min.js'" on my-server.com
```

What I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Basically what I want is to minify and gzip CSS/JS files and then to deploy to production, I'm trying to accomplish this with Capistrano(I already use Capistrano for changing some small parts of the files like you can see in finalize_update task).
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: None of that is Capistrano specific code, can you please update the question with proper example code?

Comment: That's the code which I have in deploy.rb file, I'm not getting any error but the one I described.

Comment: But you haven't included the task definitions, or anything else, so it's hard to see at first that this is Capistrano code. I'd suggest always including as much code as possible. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring that you haven't posted the task definitions, I think you might be running into the issue that each `run()` runs in it's own "channel", that is to say that actions taken (variables exported, directories changed, etc) won't affect the next one, try this (for example):

```
css_list = ["styles"]
css_path = #{current_path}/css
# run ("cd #{css_path}") // Obsolete, it would only change the directory for this line!
css_list.each do |css|
  run "cd #{css_path} && #{compressor} --type css #{css}.css -o #{css}.min.css"
  run "cd #{css_path} && gzip -c #{css}.min.css >#{js}.min.css.gz"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try, I've edited my post with task definitions this time.

Comment: Still the same problem.
failed: "sh -c 'cd  && java -jar /home/yui_compressor/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type js filter.js -o filter.min.js'"

Comment: `run` runs on the reomte server, if you are trying to run things locally use `run_locally`, or simply backticks. If you are going so far outside the Capistrano defaults, a) I'd suggest not using v2 anymore (v3 is released since ~1 week) and b) probably just look at the SSHKit library, specifically the [examples](https://github.com/leehambley/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md).

Comment: Hm, ok. One question though, where my yui-compressor is suppose to be located in, on my local machine or on the git branch I'm trying to push to production? Thanks again man

Comment: I did some adjustments on my end (some paths) and this works like a charm. Thanks man